# How to allocate cPanel resources to customers

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, cloud-hosting, resources

We are wanting to start offering hosting services to our customers with dedicated email and all those bells and whistles. We have the servers - both Windows and Linux. (Cloud Instances)

The question: How can we give users access to a server with cPanel immediately after their account has been setup and payment has been processed? Hosts like goDaddy grant access almost immediately and the customers have access to a cPanel where they can start linking hosting their sites. The users don't have access to other websites hosted on that server (shared hosting situation.) What do we need to do to setup a structure like this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you are asking you simply need to buy a WHM + cPanel Reseller Hosting account.

With that in place you can create one cPanel account for each of your customers and as you wish: *"The users don't have access to other websites hosted on that server"*

Search on Google for "Reseller Hosting WHM cPanel", and you will find millions.

Comment: We are not wanting to resell for other companies on their servers. We want to host cPanel ourselves and use our servers.

Comment: @user3035181: do you mean you have the server in your office/house?

Comment: I have 32 servers with 10GB/s fiber connection and a 10gig switch. It's in my private office.

Comment: @user3035181: cool, the hard way. If you have your own servers Herbert Musoke answer is the right one: buy a WHM+cPanel licence and install it on yoru servers.

Answer (score 1):

Acquire a license for WHM+cPanel for your server and try to do some reading on the shell scripts WHM uses to make a cPanel accounts. As you make a new account, run your custom shell scripts to automatically choose a package for the new account and other configurations and mail the logins to the user email.